# `Offset Notification Content` missing from Xcode 6.2 Beta 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, apple-watch

In recent Xcode 6.2 beta 5 update, the notification's `Offset Notification Content` option (in interface builder) is missing.

Is it has been moved to another place or renamed? I couldn't find it anywhere.

In Xcode 6.2 Beta 4.

[image: xcode-6.2beta4]

In Xcode 6.2 Beta 5 (and Xcode 6.3), the option is not there anymore.

[image: xcode-6.2beta5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes — it has been removed.
>   
>  - Apple's WatchKit Evangelist

Confirmed this was deliberately removed in Xcode 6.2 Beta 5.

I suggest this [relevant thread](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1098796#1098796) in the Developer Forums.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i just find that out too.